# GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjIvLGU 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem with Nodejs and my js code.

When I run the Nodejs in console server does not show any problems, but all time I get an error in the console from Chrome:

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjIvLGU 404 (Not Found)
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
```

**script.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

console.log("server up");

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.room);
    });
    socket.on('arriv', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.in('invitor').emit('send message',data);
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function (data) {
        socket.leave(data.room);
    });
});
```

**user.js**

```
$(function () {
    var cid = $.session.get('company');
    console.log(cid);

    var socket = io.connect();

    socket.emit("subscribe", {room: "invitor"});

    socket.on("send message", function (data){
        $('#info').append("" + data.gid + "</br>");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.123', function () {
        var gid = $(this).attr('id');
        socket.emit('arriv', {gid: gid});
    });
});
```

Comment: are you using the cdn in your html file, I was using the cdn I just downloaded the latest distribution file from here(https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/tree/master/dist) and it is solved

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to connect your socket somewhere else over localhost without port 3000. If i test your code snippets everything is OK. Your error message shows me that port 3000 is missing `" GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjIvLGU 404 (Not Found)"`.

You can try to connect manually if you change your io.connect to `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');`

Answer (score 1):

" GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjIvLGU 404 (Not Found)" means you have socket.io is not listening to your intended server. My mistake was that I instantiated the wrong server object.

In app.js file

```
var server = app.listen(config.dev.port, () => {
  console.log("Listening ..");
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid case. Say If you have `app = express();` `server = http.createServer(app);` and `io = socket(server);` then you do `app.listen()` you will get that error

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, this works:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
</script>
```